# How to use circumflex on Logitech K20 Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed Ubuntu on my desktop and I'm struggling with the use of the circumflex (This symbol: ^). I'm using a wireless Logitech k520. The keyboard is in spanish so includes this character "ñ".

Does any one know how to fix this or I better buy a new keyboard? :(